# ng-repeat on array based on length of second array

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, html

I am trying to iterate over an array using ng-repeat to display in a list. The number of records to display should be equal to the length of a second array.

```
 <ul>
  <li ng-repeat="item in firstArray"></li>
 </ul>

 var firstArray = ["a","b","c","d","e","f"]
 var secondArray = ["x","y","z"]
```

The expected result for the above example :

```
 var output = ["a","b","c"]
```

Since the length of secondArray is 3, the number of li elements would be 3 with the first three values from firstArray.

Should i use filter? I am using angularjs.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The simplest solution is to use limitTo

```
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="item in firstArray | limitTo:secondArray.length">{{item}}</li>
</ul>
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/LWh1uqNPxTy09u3MP677?p=preview

Answer (score 1):

```
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="item in firstArray" ng-if=" $index < secondArray.length "></li>
</ul>
```

Use the above code, it will work

Comment: That's performance unwise, instead of rendering only required number of elements you will create multiple watchers with `ngIf` to compare $index and array length in every $digest cycle

Answer (score 1):

You can use AngularJs filter limitTo in ng-repeat. Refer to the below example:

At angular application side:

```
    var app = angular.module('sampleapp', [])
    app.controller('samplecontrol', function ($scope) {
        $scope.firstArray = ["a","b","c","d","e","f"]
        $scope.secondArray = ["x","y","z"]
    });
```

In your view:

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="item in firstArray | limitTo:secondArray.length">{{item}}</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should use $index to test if it has to be displayed :

```
<ul >
     <li ng-repeat="item in firstArray" ng-if="$index < secondArray.length()" > </li>
 </ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just loop over your second array and access the items of the first array using `firstArray[$index]`.

```js
angular.module('myApp', [])
.controller('myCtrl', function ($scope) {
 $scope.firstArray = ["a","b","c","d","e","f"];
    $scope.secondArray = ["x","y","z"];
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller="myCtrl">
        <ul>
            <li ng-repeat="i in secondArray">
                {{firstArray[$index]}}
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: And on the way access not existing element of first array and produce way to many `li` that's needed